# how to parse this in Android with the help of DTO

Tags: java, android

How do I parse this JSON in android, I tried using this DTO

```
private Map<String , Map<String, String>> airlines;
private Map<String , Map<String, String>> airports;
private Map<String , Map<String, String>> providers;
```

but it gives an exception :-  , Cannot construct instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('Spicejet')

```
    "airlines": {
      "SG": "Spicejet",
      "AI": "Air India",
      "G8": "Go Air",
      "9W": "Jet Airways",
      "6E": "Indigo"
    },
    "airports": {
      "DEL": "New Delhi",
      "BOM": "Mumbai"
    },
    "providers": {
      "1": "MakeMyTrip",
      "2": "Cleartrip",
      "3": "Yatra",
      "4": "Musafir"
    }
```

Comment: What json api are you using to parse it to DTO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Map` holds key/pair values and values in your json fields (airlines, airports, providers). can be parsed to `Map<String, String>` directly. So simply change types of your fields to `Map<String, String>` :

```
private Map<String, String> airlines;
private Map<String, String> airports;
private Map<String, String> providers;
```